# Sphinx Search - How to Hide Archive Products

Tags: configurable-product, search, advanced-search, search-criteria, search-terms

**How I can Hide Archive Products appearing in Search results**

We are using Sphinx Search, Do anyone know how not to show some products pages showing in search results.

Thanks.

Comment: add more details to question